# Redistribute dll files

Tags: redistributable

I am reading a manual and found the following information:

> Your application should:
>
> Link against the assembly “StreamSDK_DotNET.dll”.
>
> Redistribute:
>
> “StreamSDK_DotNET.dll”
>
> “StreamSDK_CPP.dll”
>
> “Microsoft.VC8.CRT” (x86) or “Microsoft.VC9.CRT” (x64).
>
> Have the .NET Framework 2.0 or later installed.
>
> The managed code in this assembly requires the unmanaged code in the
>   C++ SDK

I am not sure how to redistribute the dll files in my program. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just zip all your files up together, and distribute that, or use a program to create installers to do stuff for you such as this: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/, then include the dll files as parts of the program, which will install everything together and you can just give out a single installer msi package.